# 16 bit limit on XDrawString arguments

Tags: xlib

From the XDrawString [man page](http://www.xfree86.org/current/XDrawString.3.html) it seems that it aceepts signed 32 bit x and y coordinates

> `int XDrawString(Display *display, Drawable d, GC
>       gc, int x, int y, char *string, int length);`

Note how both x and y are int ( ie: 32 bit signed Integer on gcc/linux2.6-i386 at least )

The problem is when I pass `y = 32767` ( 2^15 - 1) the string is drawn in the correct location but anything above this value the string is not drawn.

I suspect that internally 32 bit integers are not used but instead 16 bit signed integers for the coordinates.

Given that the man pages seem to indicate that the function accepts 32 bit integers, is there some compile option that needs to be turned to allow the use of the longer integers? Or is this a limmitation of Xlib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The X11 protocol does specify 16 bits.

Have a look at the definition for `xPolyTextReq` in `<X11/Xproto.h>`

```
typedef struct {
    CARD8 reqType;
    CARD8 pad;
    CARD16 length B16;
    Drawable drawable B32;
    GContext gc B32;
    INT16 x B16, y B16;         /* items (xTextElt) start after struct */
} xPolyTextReq;
```

Comment: Not that I know of - looking at the Xlib source suggests that all coordinates are 16 bit.  I can't see why you'd need coordinates larger than that...

Comment: I need it ;) It's not an absolute coordinate on a screen but on a scrolling lsit of widgets

Comment: that's a *big* list of widgets!

Comment: yeah a few thousand, it's a customer requirment to able to display all entries in a window :/ not practical to use ever, but it's in the contract and will be tested.

Comment: In that case, use separate scrollbar widgets that aren't part of a scrolling viewport, and redraw only those entries that are visible based on the scrollbar position.

Comment: If you had a huge high-def multimonitor setup, there could be more than 64k pixel width.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant If you have more than 64k pixels, then you need to invent X12 (X Protocol Version 12), develop it, and deploy it, because X11 is defined to 16-bit coordinates.  http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/X12 includes this limit on the list of other things someone should fix if they ever get around to trying to create X12.  64k must have seemed to be more than enough in 1987.

Comment: Haha, 64k was a lot in 1987. I remember I was quite happy with 256x192 but was a bit envious for 640x256 the Amiga people used. :-) @alanc

Comment: @alanc I know one of the [original X developers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Gettys) quite well - I'll ask him about that next time I see him